# Is there any way to use the EarlyStopping Keras function when I apply a stateful LSTM and I reset the states?

Tags: keras, lstm, stateful

I am using a stateful LSTM regression model and I would like to apply the EarlyStopping function. In stateful LSTMs as I was reading the states should be reset at each epoch. However, I noticed that when I was resetting the states the EarlyStopping method wasn't working at all. I attach also the code.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, features), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=1, restore_best_weights=True, verbose=1)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Epoch: ", epoch + 1)

    hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size, shuffle=False,
                     validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), verbose=2, callbacks=[mc, es])
    model.reset_states()
```

If I run the above code without the for loop and without the reset of states then the EarlyStopping works fine. Is there any way to apply the EarlyStopping in a for loop?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It seems that EarlyStopping could not be applied when the number of `epochs=1` in the `model.fit()` function. As I understand this happens because `EarlyStopping` is applied for one epoch each time and can work only if the number of epochs in `model.fit()` is higher than 1.

I used the following code to save the best model and halt the training process after some epochs.

```
# Number of epochs to wait before halting the training process
patience = 50

# Store the metrics of each epoch to a pandas dataframe
history = pd.DataFrame()

# Define a high loss value (this may change based on the classification problem that you have)
min_loss = 2.00

# Define a minimum accuracy value
min_acc = 0.25

# Initialize the wait variable        
wait = 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Epoch: ", epoch + 1)

    hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=1, batch_size, shuffle=False,
                     validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), verbose=2)
    model.reset_states()

    if epoch >= 0:
         if np.isnan(hist.history['val_loss'][0]):
                    break
                else:
                    if round(hist.history['val_loss'][0], 4) < min_loss:
                        min_loss = round(hist.history['val_loss'][0], 4)
                        min_acc = hist.history['val_accuracy'][0]
                        model.save('best_model')
                        history.loc[epoch, 'epoch'] = epoch + 1
                        history.loc[epoch, 'loss'] = hist.history['loss'][0]
                        history.loc[epoch, 'val_loss'] = hist.history['val_loss'][0]
                        history.loc[epoch, 'accuracy'] = hist.history['accuracy'][0]
                        history.loc[epoch, 'val_accuracy'] = hist.history['val_accuracy'][0]
                        wait = 0
                    else:
                        wait += 1
                        print('*' * 50)
                        print(f"Patience: {wait}/ {patience}", "-", "Current best val_accuracy:",
                              '{0:.5}'.format(min_acc),
                              "with loss:", '{0:.5}'.format(min_loss), f"at epoch {epoch - wait}")
                        print('*' * 50)

                        if wait < patience:
                            history.loc[epoch, 'epoch'] = epoch + 1
                            history.loc[epoch, 'loss'] = hist.history['loss'][0]
                            history.loc[epoch, 'val_loss'] = hist.history['val_loss'][0]
                            history.loc[epoch, 'accuracy'] = hist.history['accuracy'][0]
                            history.loc[epoch, 'val_accuracy'] = hist.history['val_accuracy'][0]

                        else:
                            break

history.to_csv('history.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a custom subclass of `EarlyStopping` that does not reset on subsequent calls of `model.fit()` and keeps track of the number of completed epochs:

```
class CustomES(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.started = False
        self.epoch = 0

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        if self.started:
            return
        self.started = True
        super().on_train_begin(logs)

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        super().on_epoch_begin(self.epoch, logs)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        super().on_epoch_end(self.epoch, logs)
        self.epoch += 1
```

Inside the for loop you can then break out of the loop if `es.stopped_epoch > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

For Stateful LSTM we usually call model.fit() method multiple times in for loop just to call model.reset_states() method after it, but we can reset the states without calling the fit methods multiple times by just overriding the on_epoch_end method of class EarlyStopping as below

```
class MyEarlyStopping(EarlyStopping):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.model.reset_states()
        super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
```

Then your code will look like below

```
epochs = 100  # you can change it as per you need

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, features), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
es = MyEarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=1, restore_best_weights=True, verbose=1)

hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size, shuffle=False, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), verbose=2, callbacks=[mc, es])
```

Solution 2:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

epochs = 100  # you can change it as per you need

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, features), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
es = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs: model.reset_states())

hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size, shuffle=False, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y), verbose=2, callbacks=[mc, es])
```